# Can we say "Please read it in your mind" when you ask someone to read but not out loud?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You ask a child to read a letter but not out loud.

If I say "**please read quietly**", then the child might murmur the letter.

If I just say "**Please read it**", then the child might read out loud like he is taught at school.

Can we say "**Please read it in your mind/in your thought/ in your brain...**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In your head" or "silently"  would be the idiomatic way to express this.

Alternatively "read it, but not out loud".

For most people, beyond a young age, "read" means "read in your head" and only "read aloud" needs normally to be specified.

Comment: And "silent reading" is a common school term. But it can mean in your head, or moving your lips without any sound.

Comment: "Silent reading" in school means "no chatting to your desk partner",  "no talking about the book, or about anything else" rather than particularly "read in your head"  (though it includes that)

Answer (score 0):

No, "read it in your mind/thought/brain" is not idiomatic.

A more idiomatic phrasing is "Please read it [**silently**](https://www.mhpbooks.com/have-we-always-read-silently-an-interview-with-professor-daniel-donoghue/)", which means "without making any sound".